# JDBC setDate not working with preparedstatement

Tags: date, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am pretty new to Java JDBC.  I am trying to create a JDBC preparedstatement to do a SELECT between two Oracle DATE values.
I know that data exists between these two times, as I can do the query directly.

When I execute the prepared statement from within my JDBC code, however, it returns 0 rows.

My input start and times are Long Unix time values in milliseconds.

I have tried to pare down the code to the bare minimum:

```
public static List<Oam1731Sam5Data> getData(Long startTime, Long endTime) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT timecaptured from oam1731data5 " +
            "WHERE timecaptured between ? and ?";

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement

        Date javaStartDate = new Date(startTime);
        Date javaEndDate = new Date(endTime);

        pstmt.setDate(1, javaStartDate);
        pstmt.setDate(2, javaEndDate);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String serviceId =  rs.getString("SERVICEID");
            String recordSource = rs.getString("RECORDSOURCE");
            Date timeCaptured = rs.getDate("TIMECAPTURED");
            Long oneWayMaxDelay = rs.getLong("ONEWAYMAXDELAY");
            Long twoWayMaxDelay = rs.getLong("TWOWAYMAXDELAY");
            Long twoWayMaxDelayVar = rs.getLong("TWOWAYMAXDELAYVAR");
            Long packetLoss = rs.getLong("PACKETLOSS");
        }

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: caught SQL exception, code: " + se.getErrorCode() + 
                ", message: " + se.getMessage());
    }
```

The issue is that this returns 0 rows, where the same query returns data:

select insert_date, recordsource, serviceid, timecaptured, onewaymaxdelay, twowaymaxdelay, twowaymaxdelayvar, packetloss from oam1731data5
 where timecaptured between to_date('2012-01-18 07:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 and to_date('2012-01-18 08:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 order by insert_date

DBMS_OUTPUT:

---

INSERT_DATE            RECORDSOURCE     SERVICEID                         TIMECAPTURED          ONEWAYMAXDELAY     TWOWAYMAXDELAY     TWOWAYMAXDELAYVAR     PACKETLOSS

---

1/18/2012 10:43:36 AM  EV               TAMP20-MTRO-NID1SYRC01-MTRO-NID1  1/18/2012 7:25:24 AM  40822              79693              343                   0
 1/18/2012 10:43:36 AM  EV               SYRC01-MTRO-NID1TAMP20-MTRO-NID1  1/18/2012 7:25:13 AM  39642              79720              334                   0
 1/18/2012 10:43:36 AM  EV               TAMP20-MTRO-NID1SYRC01-MTRO-NID1  1/18/2012

I have seen and ready many posts about problems somewhat like this, but have not been
able to find the key yet!

I thought about trying to make my query use a string and simply convert my dates to strings to be able to insert them for the Oracle TO_DATE function, but it seems like I should not have to do this.

And here is the output from my println statements.  Is it an issue that the dates that print do NOT show the time portion?

SQL query: SELECT timecaptured from oam1731data5 WHERE timecaptured between ? and ?
Java Oracle date: 2012-01-18 end date 2012-01-18

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mitch

Answer (score 0):

A `java.sql.Date` represents a date without time. You must use a Timestamp if you care about the time part.

The [javadoc of java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) says:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Date for your start and end dates shouldn't cause any problem. The data in the specified interval should be retrieved in that time interval (Those data that you printed which were inserted on 1/18/2012 are supposed to be retrieved in this case.) Therefore I don't think that omitting time portion is your problem.

Comment: I don't think the would be. Basically, the query searches for all the rows having their date and time between 1/18/2012 00:00:00 and 1/18/2012 00:00:00. Obviously, there isn't any.

Comment: I'm not sure that query searches all rows having date between 1/18/2012 00:00:00 and 1/18/2012 00:00:00. If that is the case, you are right obviously. The best way to understand is him to change the values of start-end dates and try that.